# Does "\n" require 1 byte when passed to the function write()?

Tags: c, stdout

I just want to know if a line break (i.e. '\n') can only be written to the stdout if 1 byte is used for such, I mean, does a line break have to be called like this?

```
write(1, "\n", 1);
```

or can it be called like this?

```
write(1, "\n", 0);
```

Comment: If you specify 0 bytes, it doesn't write anything. It's the same whether it's a printing character or newline.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bytes are bytes. There's nothing magical about `\n` that makes it not count. It has to be the former.

Comment: The "magical" thing about `\n` is that the terminal driver will treat it specially if `stdout` is connected to the terminal and the tty is not in raw mode.

Comment: So, it's 1 byte enough?

Comment: @NoahVerner Why wouldn't it be?